# How can I Integrate Ag grid (React component) in my React project?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have a problem in the integration of this plugins (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/) in my React project. The problem is in the styling: the data appears but without any table or style.

It appear this:

[image: It appear this]

Instead of this:

[image: Instead of this]

Also in another example:

it appear this:

[image: it appear this]

Instead of this:

[image: Instead of this]

This is my code:

index.js

```
"use strict";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";




class GridExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: "name",
          cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
        },
        { field: "account" },
        { field: "calls" },
        {
          field: "minutes",
          valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'"
        }
      ],
      detailCellRendererParams: {
        detailGridOptions: {
          columnDefs: [
            { field: "callId" },
            { field: "direction" },
            { field: "number" },
            {
              field: "duration",
              valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'"
            },
            { field: "switchCode" }
          ],
          onGridReady: function(params) {
            params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
          }
        },
        getDetailRowData: function(params) {
          params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
        }
      },
      onGridReady: function(params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        setTimeout(function() {
          var rowCount = 0;
          params.api.forEachNode(function(node) {
            node.setExpanded(rowCount++ === 1);
          });
        }, 500);
      }
    };
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const updateData = data => {
      params.api.setRowData(data);
    };

    httpRequest.open(
      "GET",
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-docs/latest/src/javascript-grid-master-detail/simple/data/data.json"
    );
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
      }
    };

    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var rowCount = 0;
      params.api.forEachNode(function(node) {
        node.setExpanded(rowCount++ === 1);
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            boxSizing: "border-box",
            height: "50%",
            width: "50%"
          }}
          className="ag-theme-balham"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            id="myGrid"
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            masterDetail={true}
            detailCellRendererParams={this.state.detailCellRendererParams}
            onGridReady={this.state.onGridReady}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<GridExample />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ag-Grid React Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style> html, body, #root { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">Loading ag-Grid React example&hellip;</div>

    <script>
        var appLocation = '';
        var boilerplatePath = '';
        var systemJsMap = {"ag-grid":"https:\/\/unpkg.com\/ag-grid@17.0.0\/dist\/ag-grid.js","ag-grid\/main":"https:\/\/unpkg.com\/ag-grid@17.0.0\/dist\/ag-grid.js","ag-grid-enterprise":"https:\/\/unpkg.com\/ag-grid-enterprise@17.0.0\/","ag-grid-react":"npm:ag-grid-react@17.0.0\/","ag-grid-angular":"npm:ag-grid-angular@17.0.0\/","ag-grid-vue":"npm:ag-grid-vue@17.0.0\/"}    </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `ag-grid-react` to your `package.json` along with `ag-grid` of the same version?

Also import the `ag-grid` css as below:

```
import "ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
```